# Ant build target is failing after first junit task

Tags: ant, teamcity, junit4

I have an Ant build target that performs some testing using jUnit4

```
   <target name="integrationtest" depends="init, buildtests, deploytests">
      <junit haltonfailure="false">
         <sysproperty key="driver" value="org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver" />
         <sysproperty key="screenshotDir" value="${screenshotsDir}" />
         <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${interfaceTestJar}"/>
         </classpath>
         <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${interfaceTestClasses}">
               <include name="**/tests/Test*.class" />
            </fileset>
         </batchtest>
      </junit>

      <junit haltonfailure="false">
         <sysproperty key="driver" value="org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver" />
         <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${interfaceTestJar}"/>
         </classpath>
         <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${interfaceTestClasses}">
               <include name="**/tests/Test*.class" />
            </fileset>
         </batchtest>
      </junit>

      <echo message="##teamcity[publishArtifacts '${artifactsDir}']" />
   </target>
```

First junit task is always started, but if there is any failed tests in it, the second one isn't starts (exepected to start in any case, even if first one has failed tests)

**EDIT**: Seems like there is another problem. Second jUnit is not started in any case (if first is succeed or failed). In my TeamCity build log i see the following lines

```
[integrationtest] junit
[20:06:14]: [junit] ru.company.tests.TestDateField
[20:06:30]: [junit] Process exited with code 255
```

`TestDateField` is my first test suite. After it there are some more suites and they all succeed (and the first one too).

Comment: @Olegas, please read our FAQ next time as this question is more appropriate for our sister site stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a chance your test does something like System.exit?
Did you try adding fork="true" to your junit task, so it will run in a separate JVM?

Comment: Haven't System.exit in my code. I will try to use fork="true"

Comment: Added fork to test execution - got some more error output. JUnit thinks that suit is crashed (by unknown reasons, for me all tests are done and worked right), and thus failed. The reasons of the crash is irrelevant for this question i think, will check my code in clean environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `<junit haltonfailure="no">` instead of  `<junit haltonfailure="false">`

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html), `haltonfailure` should be `yes` or `no`.

Comment: No, I think he's ok. It's a boolean; from http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html#set-magic: "your method will be passed the value true if the value specified in the build file is one of true, yes, or on and false otherwise"